# Publish error: The targeted framework not found

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I've got a strange dependency-related problem with asp.net core rc2.
I can build + run my app locally without any problems.

But as soon as I try to publish to azure (or even locally to any folder via dotnet publish) i get:

```
The targeted framework { 'Microsoft.NETCore.App': '1.0.0-rc3-004338' } was not found.
- Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
- The following versions are installed:
  1.0.0-rc2-3002702
- Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc3-004338'.
```

As far as I can understand, some of my dependencies need this rc3 version? But how can I find the problematic one? And why is my app working on my dev machine?I'm lost here :(

Any help welcome! Thank you :)

Comment: The warning seems pretty straightforward. There's a different version installed on the server than what you have on your dev machine. You need to either update the server (if that's possible) or switch to use the version available on the server.

Comment: But the I get the error on a *local* publish-to-folder, too ... ? And i cannot find any reference to version '1.0.0-rc3-004338' anywhere in my project... at least I don't know, how to find out, which dependency is needing it...

Comment: **Please** don't use `asp.net` or `core` tags when referring to ASP.NET Core. **Neither** of the two tags is related to ASP.NET Core. use `asp.net-core` instead!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem quite simple:

Problem was an unused rc3 version of Microsoft.NETCore.App in my "\Users....nuget" folder.

Solution: Simply delete the ".nuget" folder in your user folder, do a NuGet-Restore in your project - and it's working :)

Comment: I've faced the same problem while trying to run MVA "Introduction to .NET Core" course examples. It worked after removing the ".nuget" directory, updating .Net Core, and running again "dotnet restore". After that, "dotnet build" and "dotnet run" worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

Look at project.json. I solved my problem by replacing a package versions strong description. By example:

```json
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "type": "build"
    }
```

Visual Studio loads Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools version 1.0.0-preview2-21326, which depends on Microsoft.NETCore.App (> = 1.0.0-rc3-004408)

Replace version at strong "1.0.0-preview1-final" and enjoy :0)